# CTRL+ALT+DEL causes gnome to crash / ubuntu restart

Tags: gnome, 19.04

I'm experiencing a weird issue - when pressing ctrl +alt+del in ubuntu 19 - i get the standard 'restart+turn off' window.

When i press escape to exit out of that menu - menu disappears..  But I get an error message saying 'window has crashed' and the launcher disappears, and I'm presented with the menu that says 'ok' / 'restart window' (restart window does nothing -just re-opens the same menu again).

After a few minutes the computer randomly restarts :-/

Any idea on what could be happening?

Hardware: acer Swift 3 > SF315-52 - bios version 1.08 (latest)  --  ssd: corsair force mp 510 480gb

Comment: Does `ctrl`+`alt`+`del`-->`Restart` work ok?

Comment: good point - i only get an option to log out or lock.  no restart